# What must I do for "Destiny Dominated?"

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

One of the achievements in KoA is "Destiny Dominated" - I must complete the game on "Hard" difficulty.

What are the requirements for this achievement?  Can I just turn the difficulty to hard near the end of the game?  If not, since I started this run on Normal, will I have to start over and finish the game completely on Hard without changing the difficulty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling that you have to start on hard and keep it there the whole way.

I initially started on hard but I just don't really feel like fighting harder battles [for no real benefit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50084) and wanted to lower it (I now have less time to play since I'm really busy with work nowadays).  In trying to change it, I was warned that doing so `may make [me] ineligible for certain achievements`.  So by that, it sounds like just lowering it below hard at any point in the game will kill chances for the achievement.

<sub>Yeah I know, that message comes up if you change the difficulty from any level, but that wouldn't make my theory wrong.</sub>

Comment: The Xbox360Achievements.org achievement guide for Reckoning (http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=356206) indicates you need to play on Hard all the way through as well.